# length() instead of equals() to check empty string in java

Tags: java, optimization

Is there any difference in Code Optimization if we use use length() instead of equals() to check empty string in java??

```
public boolean isEmpty(String str)
{
    return str.equals("");        //NEVER do this
}

public boolean isEmpty(String str)
{
    return str.length()==0;        //Correct way to check empty
}
```

Is it true??

Comment: `str.isEmpty()` also works fine. What is really NEVER in such stuff, is that you should NEVER spend time on such nano-optimization.

Comment: just for future reference, your `isEmpty` method is not null safe. Try to avoid coding in this way.

Comment: @user902383 And what should the `isEmpty` method return when `str` is null, O master of null safety?

Comment: @Atsby fair enough, you might want to NPE in this case, which you handle outside method, but faster and better solution might be returning ie `-1` which might indicate there is no string, and might be handled more efficient. But my suggestion was in general practice not only for this particular example.

Comment: @user902383 I think you didn't get it. When str.isEmpty() throws an NPE; what do you think will happen when you call str.equals("")?! And the "reverse" "".equals(str) ... doesn't help here either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str.isEmpty()`, which internally checks the length.

Here's an implementation of the `String` class :

```
public int length() {
    return count;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
   return count == 0;
}
```

You can see that `isEmpty()` compares the length to 0.

Comment: `isEmpty()` is also a good example for "tell, don't ask" ( https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is faster to just check the length, at least on `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM`. According to my measurements, it takes only about `66%` of the time of `equals("")` to check `length() == 0`.

That being said, your program's inefficiencies almost certainly lie elsewhere.

And the built-in `isEmpty` is a good option.