# How to automatically refactor java expressions using ecplise?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I came across an intersting question at SO yesterday:
[length() instead of equals() to check empty string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386653/length-instead-of-equals-to-check-empty-string-in-java)

The interesting outcome seems to be that `someStr.equals("")` is actually "quite" slower than calling `someStr.isEmpty()`. Besides, I find "isEmpty()" to be "better style", too (as this method is a great example for the "tell, dont ask" paradigm).

Anyway; normally I would reject such "nano optimizations"; but well: we have a huge code base, many millions LOC. So, if there would be an automated, compiler-checked way to search for all occurrences of `whateverString.equals("")` to automatically replace that with a call to `whateverString.isEmpty()` ...

Well; that would mean: "some degree of code improvement" in terms of "code style" and "performance"; at zero cost.

Now I am wondering, if such "zero cost" options exist to automatically "refactor" such code; preferably with eclipse. I checked the eclipse help pages, but couldn't find anything related to "refactoring" complete expressions. Did I miss something, or do I have to turn to sed/awk (for a not so "compiler-checked" refactoring)?

I am aware that I could do a file search/replace; and most likely this will not cause problems; but the main intention of my question was to understand if eclipse (or well any other tool) could do this with "real compiler-checking" ...

Comment: Cant you just ctrl + h and search for all `.equals("")` in all your files, and replace them all with `isEmpty()`?

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of in Eclipse that does it in a compiler-checked way.  Some external tools exist -- I'm working on open-sourcing http://research.google.com/pubs/pub41876.html myself.

Comment: AFAIK there are no such options, and the file/s/r will work just fine since `.equals("")` are pretty much just for strings.